# sendEmail.pl[11242]: ERROR => ERROR => SMTP-AUTH: Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed

Tags: bash, scripting, sendmail

executing this command :

```
sendEmail.pl -s "smtp.gmail.com:587" -o tls=yes -xu xyz@gmail.com -xp password -f 'Test mail <xyz@gmail.com>' -t abc@gmail.com -u "Test report $cu_dt" -m "Hi all
Thanks,\nNote: This is a system generated automated report" -a /home/ubuntu/mongo-reports/test-report.txt
```

This command always work for me but from last 2 days i am facing this bellow error :

sendEmail.pl[11242]: ERROR => ERROR => SMTP-AUTH: Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed